# AttributeError: 'ChangeDetectorService' object has no attribute 'process'

Tags: python, mysql, class, object, attributeerror

I'm trying to develop Job program which in turn calls Service program.
`ChangeDetectorService` does have procedure named `process`. I don't know why I get the warning message:

> AttributeError: 'ChangeDetectorService' object has no attribute 'process'

"change_detector_job.py" and `ChangeDetectorService` source code are attached.

```py
# change_detector_job.py

import argparse
import datetime
# import multiprocessing
import os
# import sys
# import traceback
import sys
import traceback

from common.utils.config import Config, log_start, log_end
from ReplicationService.module.ChangeDetectorService import ChangeDetectorService

args = None
main_config = None
main_logger = None
app_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]).replace('.py', '') + '_main'


class ChangeDetectorJob:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = None
        self.logger = None
        self.env = 'test'

    def setup(self):
        self.env = args.env
        self.config = Config(args.config, app_name)
        self.logger = self.config.get_logger()

    def process(self):
        self.setup()

        t1 = log_start("ChangeDetector job started (UTC): %s" % (datetime.datetime.utcnow()), with_memory=True,
                       logger=self.logger)
        service = ChangeDetectorService(args.config, app_name)
        success = service.process()
        log_end("ChangeDetector job completed (UTC): %s" % (datetime.datetime.utcnow()), success=success, start_time=t1,
                logger=self.logger)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Data ChangeDetector Job")
        parser.add_argument("-e", "--env", default="test", choices=['test', 'dev', 'uat', 'prd'],
                            help="environment this job to be deployed (default %default)")
        parser.add_argument("-c", "--config", default="../config/cmo_backend_local_config.ini",
                            help="config file (test only default %default)")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        ini_file = args.config
        main_config = Config(ini_file, app_name)
        main_logger = main_config.get_logger()

 #      multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
        main_logger.info("**** ChangeDetector job started (UTC): %s" % datetime.datetime.utcnow())

        # service = ChangeDetectorService(args.config, app_name)
        # success = service.process()

        ChangeDetectorJob().process()

        main_logger.info("**** ChangeDetector job completed (UTC): %s" % datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    except Exception as error:
        if main_logger is not None:
            main_logger.error("Exception encountered: " + str(error))
            main_logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        traceback.print_exc()
        print("FINAL EXCEPTION OUT .... ")
```

```py
# ChangeDetectorService.py

# import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from common.database.mysql_manager import MysqlManager
from common.utils.config import Config, log_start, log_end

# mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',port="3306",user='user',password='pass',database='dbname')
import mysql.connector
# rows_inserted = 0;

class ChangeDetectorService:
    #
    def __init__(self, ini_file, app_name):
        self.config_object = Config(ini_file, app_name)
        self.logger = self.config_object.get_logger()
        self.mysql_manager = MysqlManager(self.config_object)

try:
    def get_connection(self):`enter code here`
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='zzzz',
                                             host='host',
                                             database='dbname'
                                             )

        return connection


    def init_change_detector(self):
        print("Change Detector started at " + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

        mysqlManager = MysqlManager
        # conn = self.get_connection()
        conn = self.mysqlManager.get_db_connection()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = ('SELECT table_name, column_name, key_name '
                 'FROM cmooptimizationsvc.csj_chngdtct_tab_col '
                 'WHERE is_active=1 '
                 'ORDER BY table_name, column_name')
        cursor.execute(query)
        # get all records
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        for record in records:
            self.process_col_tab_chg(record[0], record[1], record[2])
        if  conn.is_connected():
            conn.close()
            cursor.close()


    def insert_change_log(self, table_name, key_name, attr_name, old_attr_value, new_attr_value):
        # global rows_inserted;
        insert_query = """INSERT INTO csj_shipment_changelog(table_name, key_name,
                                                                 attr_name, old_attr_value,
                                                                 new_attr_value)
                                                               VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        conn = self.get_connection()

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        tuple1 = (table_name, key_name, attr_name, old_attr_value, new_attr_value)
        #        tuples.append(tuple1)
        cursor.execute(insert_query, tuple1)
        #        rows_inserted += 1
        #       print( rows_inserted );
        #       if (rows_inserted%10==0):
        #          cursor.executemany(insert_query, tuples)
        conn.commit()
        rows_inserted = 0
        #         tuples = []
        #  quit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()


    # Look for Shipment, in past date
    def find_past_shipment(self,
                           table_name,
                           key_name,
                           column_name,
                           before_date,
                           curr_key
                           ):
        saved_col_name = column_name
        saved_key_name = key_name
        conn = self.get_connection()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = 'SELECT  ' + saved_key_name + ' , ' + saved_col_name + ' FROM ' + table_name \
                + ' where rec_cre_dt_utc < ' + "'" + before_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') + "'" \
                + ' and shipment_num = ' + "'" + curr_key + "'" + ' order by rec_cre_dt_utc desc LIMIT 1'
        cursor.execute(query)
        records = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        if records is not None:
            past_attr_val = records[1]
            return past_attr_val
        else:
            return 0

    def process_col_tab_chg(self,table_name, column_name, key_name):
        saved_key_name = key_name
        saved_col_name = column_name
        old_val = 0
        ini_time_for_now = datetime.now()
        date_before_1day = ini_time_for_now - timedelta(days=1)
        query = 'SELECT  ' + key_name + ' , ' + saved_col_name + ' , ' + ' rec_cre_dt_utc FROM ' + table_name \
                + ' where rec_cre_dt_utc >= ' + "'" + date_before_1day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') + "'"
        conn = self.get_connection()
         cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        for (key_name, column_name, rec_cre_dt_utc) in cursor:
            curr_attr_val = column_name
            curr_key_val = key_name
            old_val = self.find_past_shipment(table_name,
                                              saved_key_name,
                                              saved_col_name,
                                              rec_cre_dt_utc,
                                              curr_key_val
                                              )
            if   curr_attr_val != old_val \
                    and  old_val != 0:
                self.insert_change_log(table_name, key_name, saved_col_name, old_val, curr_attr_val )
            else:
                continue

        cursor.close
        conn.close()


    def cleanup():
        print("Change Detector stopped " + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))


    def process():
        start = datetime.now()
        init_change_detector()
        #                  cleanup()
        #            mysqlManager = MysqlManager
        #            conn = get_connection(self)
        #             conn = self.mysql_manager.get_db_connection()
        #             cursor = conn.cursor()
        #             query = ('SELECT table_name, column_name, key_name '
        #                      'FROM cmooptimizationsvc.csj_chngdtct_tab_col '
        #                      'WHERE is_active=1 '
        #                      'ORDER BY table_name, column_name')
        #             cursor.execute(query)
        #             # get all records
        #             records = cursor.fetchall()
        #             for record in records:
        #                 self.process_col_tab_chg(record[0], record[1], record[2])
        #             if  conn.is_connected():
        #                 conn.close()
        #                 cursor.close()
        end = datetime.now()
        time_diff = (end - start)
        execution_time = time_diff.total_seconds()
        print("Elapsed time(secs): " + str(execution_time))


except Exception as e:
    print("Exception " + e)
finally:
    cleanup()

#    if __name__ == "__main__":
#       main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `AttributeError` when you try to use an attribute (method or property) which does not exist for your object (class). In this case, the error states that `ChangeDetectorService` is under the question:

> AttributeError: 'ChangeDetectorService' object has no attribute 'process'

In your error message, right before the above line, you should see the code line which caused this error:

```py
success = service.process()
```

`service` was assigned to this expression:

```py
service = ChangeDetectorService(args.config, app_name)
```

So, `service` is of type (class) `ChangeDetectorService`. It must be it... Inspecting the source code we see this:

```py
class ChangeDetectorService:
    #
    def __init__(self, ini_file, app_name):
        self.config_object = Config(ini_file, app_name)
        self.logger = self.config_object.get_logger()
        self.mysql_manager = MysqlManager(self.config_object)

try:
...
```

`try` has the same indentation as `class`. So, `try` has closed the `ChangeDetectorService` class definition. It means, your `ChangeDetectorService` class has only the constructor (`__init__`) defined. `ChangeDetectorService` class does not have any other method defined. It means, it doesn't have `process` method either. That's why you get the error. If you want `ChangeDetectorService` class to have the `process` method, make sure `try` or anything else does not interfere with all the method definitions of the class.

Comment: Thank you ZygD for your detailed explanation.  :-)